# HsqlDB with spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image: Project structure look like this]

This the pom.xml for maven build project that I am using to resolve dependencies.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.raj</groupId>
    <artifactId>hSQLdb1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below are the properties file for my sample application here I am using applicationproperties and application-hsqldb.properties

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=hsqldb
# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true

**application-hsqldb.properties**

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

# Initialization
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/data/hsqldb/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data/hsqldb/data.sql
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO EMP(f_name, l_name) VALUES('Rajendar','Kumar');
INSERT INTO EMP(f_name, l_name) VALUES('Ramesh','Kumar');
```

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE EMP IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE emp (
    id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    f_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    l_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Below is the controller for my rest services that have two service for greeting and read data from database

```
import com.raj.hSQLdb.pojo.Employee;
import com.raj.hSQLdb.pojo.Greating;
import com.raj.hSQLdb.service.impl.ProcessEmpDataService;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class Controller{

    @Autowired
    private ProcessEmpDataService empDataService;

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="Rajendar") String name) {
        return new Greating(String.valueOf(counter.incrementAndGet()), String.format(template, name)).toString();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/read"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> read(Long id) {
        Employee response = empDataService.findOne(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
package com.raj.hSQLdb.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="emp")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5667869092245806231L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "f_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "l_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
}
```

** Greating **

```
package com.raj.hSQLdb.pojo;

public class Greating{

    public Greating(String code, String message) {
        this.code=code;
        this.message=message;
    }
    protected String code;
    private String message;
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
package com.raj.hSQLdb.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.raj.hSQLdb.pojo.Employee;
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

}
```

**Service**

```
package com.raj.hSQLdb.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.raj.hSQLdb.pojo.Employee;
import com.raj.hSQLdb.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Component
public class ProcessEmpDataService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    public Employee findOne(Long id) {
        Employee emp = repository.findOne(id);
        return emp;
    }
}
```

**main class to run the application**

```
package com.raj.hSQLdb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServletInitializer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
        }

}
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency`. you never has defined a datasource

Comment: @Jens I have tried with below application.properties

Comment: spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = sa

spring.datasource.schema=classpath:data/hsqldb/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data/hsqldb/data.sql

Comment: @Jens more over this all the configuration for hsqldb is managed by Springboot itself, so datasource should be managed by spring-boot itself.

Comment: Could you show more of your code? Do you have RestController or something? And how do you inject and use the Repository? I just repeated you project in minimal form and it runs fine even without application.properties, so I think that problem not in maven config.

Comment: I don't see where the problem is coming from but I'd like to take a deeper look. Can you please create a sample that reproduces the problem and create an issue in the Spring Boot tracker?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll do I need to make any entry in application.properties for hsqldb line spring.datasource.url     spring.datasource.driver-class-name       spring.jpa.database-platform etc many thanks in advance

Comment: @StephaneNicoll   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "hsqldb" are currently active).
     at

Comment: Might be worth checking that the HSQLDB jar in Maven's cache wasn't corrupted when it was downloaded. Try deleting it from the cache and rebuilding your app.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have tried after deleting .m2 repo as well but still facing the same issue